# Set Datetime to 00:00:00 in LogicApp

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

currently I am working with a Logic App, I want to set the hours to a given DateTimeFormat to 00:00:00 with a Variable. After that I try to add an int variable as hours with it, but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(), -utcNow().Hour + variables('Daytime')), concat('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss', variables('DateTimeOffset')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to know what values the variables have in them because without it, it's not as easy to provide a complete answer, but, bottom line, you can't use `+` like you have in the expression.

If you want to add and minus, etc., you need to use the inbuilt function `add`.

The expression builder is a function based approach.

Without knowing exactly what you want to achieve, something like this will help you along ...

```
concat(addHours(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 6, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), '+06:00')
```

... but will need to be cleaned up.

You also need to replace my hardcoded values with your variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. The variable "Daytime" is a fix given number between 0-23 and it's datatype is int. The variable "DateTimeOffset" holds an offset which should be added to the 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'-Format

Fyi: Also found out, that utcNow() has no property like ".Hour"